# cookies won't be deleted using js i am using the method below

Tags: javascript

```
function removeItem(key){
    document.cookie = `${key}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`;
console.log(key+"Deleted");
    console.log(document.cookie);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [these](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) code snippets from w3schools

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 365);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided.  If the linked page gets moved or deleted, then the answer is of little help.

Comment: I have tried this idea but the cookies are not deleted

Comment: I use this function, works for me: `setCookie('remember', '', -1);`